# Creating a custom control with compiled bindings in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Microsoft documentation states that:

> Compiled bindings are currently disabled for any binding expressions that define the Source property. This is because the Source property is always set using the x:Reference markup extension, which can't be resolved at compile time.

I need to use use Source to reference the controls bindable properties

`ImageSource="{Binding Image, Source={x:Reference Host}}"`

```
public UriImageSource Image
{
     get => (UriImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty);
     set => SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: ... and your problem is what exactly? AFAIK, the compilation is automatically disabled in that case, so you shouldn't need to do anything. Are you getting some error? Maybe explicitly disable on that file's xaml: `[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]`. google `xamarin forms compiled bindings`, find the doc, for description (which only tells how to turn it ON, you want it OFF).

Comment: I want it on for the performance benefits. I'm building my UI using many components and could not find any guide on how to use compiled bindings with those.

Comment: Microsoft says that is not possible. And explains why. Thus, they automatically turn it off in that case.